# LinkedIn Integration with iCIMS (ATS) Feature

Tags: linkedin-api

LinkedIn has previously supported an integration with the applicant tracking system, iCIMS to allow the functionality of the Social Distribution feature. Recently, iCIMS indicated that the feature is no longer working as a result of an update to LinkedIn's integration. This tool allows iCIMS users to promote jobs on LinkedIn by creating and managing scheduled posts within iCIMS. Since the updates have been made, the posts no longer allow images and or variables within the system to populate information. As a result, we have had to stop utilizing the feature. We are reaching out to understand if there is an expected ETA as to when/if this issue will be resolved.

Thank you in advance for the assistance. #linkedin